# Apply italic effect in the part of Text property of Label in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

This is my snippet in Xamarin.forms.

```
grid.Children.Add (new Label {Text = "Italic, Bold",
                            XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
                            YAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
                            FontSize = 30
                        }, 1, 1);
```

I need to make "Italic" Italic font and bold "Bold".

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved it.

```
var fs = new FormattedString ();
fs.Spans.Add (new Span { Text="Italic", ForegroundColor = Color.Gray, FontSize = 20, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Italic });
fs.Spans.Add (new Span { Text=", Bold", ForegroundColor = Color.Gray, FontSize = 20, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold });
labelFormatted.FormattedText = fs;
```

Comment: In XAML, this will be -
FontAttributes="Italic"
FontAttributes="Bold"